# Derivative of $\tan x$ without using derivative of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives

$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$.

This means that when we find the derivative of $\tan x$, we would need to have the derivative of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, which are $\cos x$ and $-\sin x$ respectively.  However, I would like to know how to find $\tan x$ can be found without using the derivative of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.  Alternatively, a proof of how the derivative of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ equal to $\cos x$ and $-\sin x$ respectively, would help too.

Do note that the answer is a positive one.

Comment: How do you define $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: What do you mean define?

Comment: Don't you know what a definition is? If the answer is negative, then you are wasting your time here.

Comment: Oh,  Well it is positive.  I will add that into my question

Comment: He meant 'If the answer to my question (on whether or not you know what a definition is), ...' The point is there are many equivalent definitions of cosine and sine, and a proof of the value of their derivatives depends on the definition used.

Comment: I am rather confused right now.  My definition of sin and cos here is such that 0<=x<=90.  Is that better?

Comment: You may use $\;\displaystyle\tan(h)=\tan((x+h)-x)=\frac{\tan(x+h)-\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x+h)\tan(x)}\;$ (if you know this!) to evaluate $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\tan(x+h)-\tan(x)}h$.

Comment: Downvotes please explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $\cos{x}\neq0$ we have: $$(\tan{x})'=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\tan(x+h)-\tan{x}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{h}}{h\cos{x}\cos(x+h)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$$
because $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{h}}{h}=1$ and $\cos$ is a continuous function.